# mysql syntax issue in C#.net

Tags: c#, mysql

Basically the problem is how to write a `sql` syntax in `C#` to insert some value to a specific location of the table. there is a table called users_log in my database and three columns `UserID`, `UserPassword` and `LogedTime`. Both `UserID` and `User PassWord` have been already filled with values. but i want to insert user Log in time to `LogedTime` column when ever the user logs in. But it has to be inserted into the place(LogedTime) in which user logs in. my insert sqlString show an `null reference` when it is run. 
this is my code

```
public void logedTime()
{
        MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(sqlCon);
        con1.Open();

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string logedTime = dt.ToString();

        string timeIns = "insert into users_log(LogedTime) values('" + logedTime + "') where UserID='"+dataR["UserID"]+"';";

        MySqlCommand cd1 = new MySqlCommand(timeIns, con1);

        dataR = cd1.ExecuteReader();
        con1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet isn't complete, where is `dataR` defined and populated?

Comment: ahh its defined out side of the method to make it public

Comment: dataR is a mysqlDataReader

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html

Comment: `string timeIns = "update users_log set LogedTime = " + logedTime  + " where UserID='"+dataR["UserID"]+"'";`

Comment: LogedTime is dateTime UserID is varchar

Comment: i dis still null reference comes

Comment: @Grant Winney ahhh i wasn't about to force anyone to help me commenting  like this. sorry i was helpless but now its solved. i thought commenting will keep this post to be up among many different posts. i m new to this site too.I'm studying these from my own. self studying. Thanks a lot for the help Grant Winney and all the others who helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your query:

```
insert into users_log(LogedTime)
    values('" + logedTime + "')
    where UserID='"+dataR["UserID"]+"'";
```

This is not correct syntax for an `insert`.  I suspect that you want an `update`:

```
update users_log
    set logedTime = ".logedTime ."
    where UserID='"+dataR["UserID"]+"'";
```

EDIT:

If you really do want to insert another record, then the syntax would be:

```
insert into users_log(userId, LogedTime)
    values('"+dataR["UserID"]+"', '" + logedTime + "');
```

Comment: @user3304413 . . . The SQL statement is the SQL statement, so you should put this into your C# code.

Comment: i dis still null reference comes

Comment: @GrantWinney  set logedTime = ".logedTime ." why using dots in here?

Comment: @GrantWinney   no no not another record if grant winney logs in i want the time when grant logs in to be inserted in to the LogedTime column where UserID is grant

Comment: i replaced this   where UserID='"+dataR["UserID"]+"'"; with where UserID='" + textBox1.Text + "'"; coz textbox1 is the place where i enter my UserID. and now it says sql syntax error.

Comment: YOOOOOO YOOOOOO problem SOlved